# Run scalatest in main instead of test through sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

Say I have a Scalatest file in the main directory, is there a sbt command to run the test such as `testOnly` or `runMain'? On IntelliJ, you are given the option to run the test.

Comment: So you want to run all the tests in a test class, or you just want to run a particular `test("hello this is a test"){}` within a test class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use `test-only`. From the scalatest [user guide](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_scalatest_with_sbt):

```
test-only org.acme.RedSuite org.acme.BlueSuite
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried `testOnly` a moment ago, and it worked for a Scalatest file in main directory instead of being not found.